# how to calculate amount of angular bindings which was made on a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I implementing angularjs application and need to know, how much angular bindings I currently have on my page. How can I calculate it?

Comment: Are you looking to figure this out from an understanding/performance point of view, or do you need to actually calculate this in code (as in to display it in your app)?

Comment: For both matters. First to measure performance, second - to see how things goes and where I stand at current moment.

Answer (score 3):

From a debug/understanding/performance point of view, I recommend you try out the [AngularJS Batarang Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en). You install the extension, load up your angular application in Chrome, hit F12 to bring up developer tools, and then go to the "AngularJS" tab that the extension creates. The Performance page specifically will tell you about your bindings - it lists out all of your watch expressions and how long they are taking to calculate.